# $.post Does not seem to be sending

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

$.post() does not seem to be working, as in the request is not even being sent. Meanwhile if I switch this call to $.get it works perfectly as it should, the request is sent, and the return data is returned.

```
<script>
$.post('/ajaxcreport/',function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  When you debug this, is the code executed at all?  In your browser's debugging tools, is an HTTP request made?  What is the server's response?

Comment: The type of request the server expects is very important. Simply changing from `$.get` to `$.post` in JS isn't enough - you need to amend the server side code too

Comment: I am amending the requisite server side code, and yes the javascript code is running, (if I place an alert at the end it fires)

Answer (score 0):

The [`$.post()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) should include the actual data you are sending (if you are updating the database with new information).

```
var url = '/path/to';
var newData = somedata;
var successFunction = function(){};
$.post(url, newData, successFunction);
```

If you are simply retrieving data, stick with `$.get()`.